# How to catch fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)

Tags: php, exception, doctrine, symfony-1.4, fetch

In my Symfony 1.4 project in one of my class.php file I used the following codes to execute query and fetch object.

```
$statement = Doctrine_Manager::connection()->execute($query);
$resultset = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

I tried to use try-catch block to catch any run-time exceptions. I can easily do that for the first line like

```
    try {
        $statement = Doctrine_Manager::connection()->execute($query);
    } 
    catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo "custom error message";
    }
```

But, I this dosen't work for the second line. It always show the following error when I run the page

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in
>
> \lib\model\doctrine\DeductionInfo.class.php on line 104

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you tell me why do you use this method to query your database? The goal of using an ORM is to *avoid* building query from scratch but to use model abstraction...

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. This is a half done old software that I have to finish

Answer (score 1):

Of course it seems to be an invalid query or something like that, resulting in a non-object in your var $statement. Debug or var_dump your $statement var at first.

Doctrine btw is on top of PDO. By default a PDO construct throws an exception on error. But you have to set error handling for quering to exception (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) if you want to use try-catch statements. I don't know exactly the way Doctrine 1 handles this.